# confused over the meaning of a functor having both adjoints

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I am quite confused over what it means for a functor to have "both adjoints". From what I understand. Suppose we have $F:X \rightarrow A$ and $G:A\rightarrow X$. We might say $F$ is the left adjoint to $G$, thus $G$ have a left adjoint. Or we can say $G$ is the right adjoint to $F$, thus $F$ has a right adjoint.

My confusion is to what we mean, say, for $F:X\rightarrow A$ to have "both" adjoints ?

Cheers !

Comment: It means that $F$ has a left adjoint $G$ and also a right adjoint $H$.

Comment: @Randall. Thank you for the reply, my source of the confusion is the statement "$F$ has a left adjoint G", it looks like $G$ is also a functor from $X \rightarrow A$.

Comment: No, if $F: X \to A$ and $G$ is left adjoint to $F$, then $G: A \to X$.  If $H$ is right adjoint to $F$ then $H: A \to X$, too, but this need not be related to $G$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095189/a-functor-that-has-both-left-and-right-adjoints?rq=1) for an example.